# postfix master.cf configuration from database

Tags: postfix, ssl-certificate

I am wondering if it is possible to configure postfix `master.cf` file from database.
Same as, for example, in `main.cf` one can set

```
alias_maps = pgsql:/etc/postfix/pgsql-aliases.cf
```

What I'm specifically trying to do is to have several SSL certificates.
It can be done fairly easily by modifying `master.cf` as shown [here](http://blog.wpkg.org/2013/07/31/postfix-and-multiple-ssl-certificates/).

However, I am trying to avoid having to restart the server. I though that the cleanest way to do that would be to configure the `master.cf` from a database.

If this is not possible, is there any way around restarting the server, or in the worst case, making sure that no mail is lost?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to have several main.cf configurations and activate one or the other? what about just copying or soft linking the right one? And for getting the new configuration you don't need to restart, you can just `reload` postfix. Also even if you restart you wouldn't be losing email since messages tend to be re-sent if something went wrong (also you want to have a backup mail server)

Comment: So if I am reloading postfix, is still able to receive and save mail? I'm ok with having several `main.cf` files.

Comment: Yes, reload just re-reads configuration files, postfix still runs. Even if you restart it it's very unlikely that you'll lose any email.

Comment: Sweet. That, in my books is an answer, so if you want to post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the new Postfix configuration you don't need to restart, you can just reload postfix [as recommended](http://www.postfix.org/postfix.1.html) : "in order to refresh the Postfix mail system after  a  con-
              figuration  change,  do  not  use the start and stop commands in
              succession. Use the reload command instead."